# Retrieve Data from DataTable and assign to Dialog Modal using jQuery

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have below Data in DataTable.

```
| InvoiceNo |  Fruits   |     Date     | Description | Action |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|   001     |   Apple   | Jun 12, 2012 |      -      | Edit   |
|   001     |   Banana  | Jun 12, 2012 |      -      | Edit   |
|   001     |   Mango   | Jun 12, 2012 |      -      | Edit   |
|   002     |   Apples  | Jun 12, 2012 |      -      | Edit   |
|   002     |   Mango   | Jun 12, 2012 |      -      | Edit   |
```

when i click `Edit` in `Action` column, Data will be shown in another `DataTable`, which is in `Dialog Modal`, i want to take data from the above `DataTable` by `InvoiceNo` all the rows will be shown in `Dialog Modals DataTable`. I have `filtered` the dataTable on Edit click by `Invoice No`, but all of the rows from dataTable are passed to `Dialog Modal DataTable`. I want to get data from DataTable not from DataBase again.
Any help...

Comment: Are you using Jquery DataTables? Share your code.

Comment: Did you check this editor.datatables.net/release/DataTables/extras/Editor/examples/inlineControls.html?

Answer (score 2):

Sure here you go , add this to the document ready along with the datatable init code
(I paraphrased html elements as i do not know what your source html setup is)
Using jquery 1.9

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var passData ={}; //if you want the table array to be global

$(document).on("click", "#yourtableID tbody tr #edit", function(){
    var nTr = this; 
    var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition(this);

    var aData = oTable.fnGetData(aPos); //if you want the table array to be local
    passData = aData;
    console.log(aData); //view console to see entire row object
    alert(aData['InvoiceNo']); //if your data is key:value
    alert(aData[1]); //if your table is without keys
});
```

so heres an example of modal usage, here im setting the title

```
$( '#dialog-modal' ).dialog( 
  'option', 'title', passData['InvoiceNo']+' - '+passData['Fruit'] 
  ).dialog( 'open' );               
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic modal dialog initialization used to pass data from the datatable to the dialog without performing another AJAX call. Note: you will need to have TableTools.js included on the page for the open function to work.

```
$("#your-dialog-id").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    width: 450,
    buttons: {
        Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    },
    open: function() {
        var aVariable = TableTools.fnGetInstance('yourDataTableName').fnGetSelectedData()[0];

        $(this).find("input[name=input1]").val(aVariable.INVOICE_NO);
        $(this).find("input[name=input1]").val(aVariable.FRUITS);
        $(this).find("input[name=input2]").val(aVariable.DATE);
        $(this).find("input[name=input3]").val(aVariable.DESCRIPTION);
        $(this).find("input[name=input3]").val(aVariable.ACTION);
    }
});
```

To get this dialog to open you could do the following:

```
$("#yourDataTableName tbody").on( 'dblclick', 'tr:not(:has(td.dataTables_empty))', function (e) {
        TableTools.fnGetInstance('yourDataTableName').fnSelect(this);
        $("#your-dialog-id").dialog("open");
});
```